# How to deploy node.js app without heroku aws or other cloud computing

Tags: node.js, cloud, nodejs-server

I have plenty of spare machines that i could use for computing, what would be the best way to deploy a nodeJS app to the web without going through a middle man (aws, azure, heroku)?